# Phonegap facebook plugin for android gives me an oauthexception

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins, cordova

seriously going insane here....

I'm trying to get the phonegap facebook plugin for android to work, but it's really driving me up the wall (no pun intented).

I am using the code from https://github.com/irnc/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/tree/oauth-2.0+irnc, at least I think I am.

I appear to have two problems:

1. the following callback in the login (from pg-plugin-fb-connect) gives an error because "FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(response.authResponse, response.status);" cannot be found. Am I using an incorrect facebook sdk? **Apparently no, see edit below**

   ```
   PhoneGap.exec(function (response) {
           console.log('PG.FB.login.success: ' + JSON.stringify(response) + ', store into localStorage ...');
           localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(response));

           FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(response.authResponse, response.status);

           if (cb) {
               cb(response);
           }
       }, null, service, 'login', ['publish_stream', 'read_stream']);
   },
   ```
2. **When I comment the** *FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(response.authResponse, response.status);* statement, my login returns successfull! I get an authresponse with an accesstoken and status set to connected. When I try to execute the following code (on success callback)

   ```
   FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response.error, null, 4));
       alert('We are very sorry, but somthing went wrong');
   } else {
     alert('Message was successfully posted to your wall!');
   }
   });
   ```

it gives me an oauthexception message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I authenticated with 'read_stream, publish_stream' permissions.

These two are probably related, but I can't find anything about the setAuthReponse call in the facebook api.

**EDIT** help is apparently not on it's way, but i've continued my quest to get this to work.

The facebook js sdk I got from the github repo's are all using the 'old' auth methods. I've downloaded the new facebook js sdk and FB.Auth.setAuthResponse is there. I copied the code to my existing js sdk and changed all calls to setSession to setAuthRepsonse. Everything is working fine, except that the **access token doesn't appear to be posted when I make above FB.api calls**. After these changes, the error remains exactly the same!

Oh yeah, I also changed the check in the login callback to check for authResponse instead of session (it's in the example).

Help is more than welcome,
rinze

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed this. Basically the ConnectPlugin.java is still returning a "session" response object instead of the "authResponse" that the new SDK expects.

See https://github.com/odbol/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/commit/0ef84e29603338930ff82fc6d6ef8525b668077d for details.